# using handlebars.js for templating removes spaces in a given field

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm using the handlebars.js for templating, but I encounter some problems
This is my code:

```
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        if (jsonData.length) {
            $('#comments').html("");
            var source_g = $('#comments_template').html();
            var template_g = Handlebars.compile(source_g);
            for ( var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                var data = jsonData[i];
                console.log("comments to display : "+data.comment);
                var html = template_g(data);
                $('#comments').append(html);
            }
```

This line:

```
console.log("comments to display : "+data.comment);
```

returns

> "test --space-- --space-- --space-- my --space-- --space-- --space-- Test"

and in the template I get:

> "test my Test"

All the spaces are removed !!

How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template just put the comment between the tag

`<pre> {{comment}} </pre>`

In that case the spaces will not be removed :)